# Django selecting distinct field not working

Tags: python, mysql, django, distinct

I have 2 models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
        """
        Team model for creating a basic team.
        """
        image = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=_profile_image_directory(), verbose_name=u'Logo', help_text=u'Uploading a team logo is highly recommended.', blank=True)
        name = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Team Name', max_length=100)
        school = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'School Name', max_length=100, blank=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        state = USStateField(blank=True)
        description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=175)
        members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='TeamMember')
        key = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=False, blank=True)
        private = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
        twitter = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Twitter handle', max_length=15, blank=True)
        hashtag = models.CharField(help_text=u'Tweets containing this hashtag will be pulled into your team\'s Twitter feed', max_length=20, blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.name)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name = u'Team'
                verbose_name_plural = u'Teams'
                unique_together = ('name', 'school', 'state')

class TeamMember(models.Model):
        """
        Team model for connecting users with teams.
        """
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
        number = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
        position = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        start = models.CharField(help_text=u'Year only. Format: 2004', max_length=4, blank=True)
        end = models.CharField(help_text=u'Year only. Leave blank for current team', max_length=4, blank=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I'm trying to search all of the teammates of the current user by name, so I have a query here:

```
TeamMember.objects.filter(team__members=request.user).filter(user__username__icontains=query).exclude(user=request.user)
```

This query works, but I many times get duplicate users if that user is in several of the same teams as you, so I want to do a DISTINCT or GROUP BY on the user field, but everything I try isn't working.

I've tried:

```
TeamMember.objects.filter(team__members=request.user).filter(user__username__icontains=query).exclude(user=request.user).distinct("user")
```

This one works, but doesn't give me enough information about the user, just their id because it gets converted to a dict:

```
TeamMember.objects.filter(team__members=request.user).filter(user__username__icontains=query).exclude(user=request.user).values("user").distinct()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: has my answer helps with your issue? Can I improve it? Let me know if this is a wrong answer in order to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns distinct `TeamMember`not distinct `user`.

In order to get  distinct `user`:

```
user.objects.filter( 
                teammember__team__teammember__user__icontains=query
          ).exclude(user=request.user).distinct()
```

Explained: distincts `users` that they `teammember` has a `team` that is related to a `teammember` that has a `user` that contains `query` all this excluding logged user.